# Show purchases history

Tags: php, sql

I need some help.
I am about to create a small e-shop and I want to add purschase history for every user.

I have this, but it does not work like I want.

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM transactions INNER JOIN cds ON transactions.cdCode=cds.code WHERE usrId='$userId' ORDER BY transactionId";
$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==0)
    echo "No purchases";
echo "<table>";

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['transactionId']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['name']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['cdQuantity']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['price']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['tDate']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['status']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

the sql file:

```
CREATE TABLE transactions (
    transactionId varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    usrId INT NOT NULL,
    cdCode varchar(35),
    cdQuantity int,
    tDate text,
    status text,
    PRIMARY KEY(transactionId,usrId,cdCode),
    FOREIGN KEY(usrId) REFERENCES users(userId),
    FOREIGN KEY(cdCode) REFERENCES cds(code)
);
```

It prints something like this:

```
> purchaseId  cdName quantity price date status
> 1e963a1d  CdName  1   price   2015-12-12:14:08    Pending
> 1e963a1d  CdName      1   price   2015-12-12:14:08    Pending
> 1e963a1d  CdName      1   price   2015-12-12:14:08    Pending
> 1e963a1d  CdName  1   price   2015-12-12:14:08    Pending
> 1f2b8183  CdName  1   price   2015-12-12:14:20    Pending
> 1f2b8183  CdName      1   price   2015-12-12:14:20    Pending
> 1f2b8183  CdName      1   price   2015-12-12:14:20    Pending
```

I want to group the purchases by purchaseId in different tables in order to calculate the total cost of every purschase.

Comment: I'm confused... cdCode or cdName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` along with your existing query like

```
SELECT t.*, SUM(t.price) as total_price
FROM transactions t
INNER JOIN cds c ON t.cdCode = c.code 
WHERE t.usrId = '$userId' 
GROUP BY t.purchaseId
ORDER BY transactionId;
```